# SQL query for the given table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, Student and Supervisor:

- `STUDENT`(supervisorid(pk),name,email....)
- `SUPERVISOR`(supervisorid(pk),name,email....)

Now I need to print supervisor name, email and the # of students under the supervisor (they will have same supervisor id).  Something like:

```
select supervisorname,
       supervisoremail,
       tot_stud as (select count(*) 
                           Phd_Student s 
                     where s.supervisor_id = r.supervisor_id) 
  from Phd_Supervisor r
```

Can you please tell me the SQL query for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select supervisorname,
   supervisoremail,
   (select count(*) 
    from Phd_Student s 
    where s.supervisor_id = r.supervisor_id) as tot_stud
from Phd_Supervisor r
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the `group by` clause for this query.  You can specify all of the fields that you want to display, as well as the `count(*)`, join the tables, relate the tables , and then put in your `group by` clause, listing all of the display fields,(without the `count(*)`), as those are the fields you are grouping the students by to get their count.

Comment: can you give me the exact query

Comment: Peter, I'd love to, but you have come so far with your query that with just the explanation I have give, you can probably work it out from there - and it will be yours!  Let me know if you have any trouble with it.